# What is the difference between Mean Imputation (vs) Item Mean Imputation (vs) Person Mean Imputation?

Tags: data-imputation

I just learned that we can handle missing data using Imputation techniques, I would like to know difference between Mean Imputation & Item Mean Imputation & Person Mean Imputation and when to use it.

Comment: Does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12867/multiple-imputation-on-single-subscale-item-or-subscale-scores?rq=1 help?

Comment: Hi @mdewey I think this is not what I was looking for.